# XSLT copy output without node and filter on key

Tags: xml, xslt

XML Input:

```
<root>
    <results>
        <output>
            <tag1>
                <tag2>
                    <tag3>
                        <tag4>2016-03-27T14:27:10.542+03:00</tag4>
                    </tag3>
                    <tag5/>
                    <tag6>
                        <record>
                            <column name="Result">smth</column>
                        </record>
                    </tag6>
                </tag2>
            </tag1>
        </output>
    </results>
    <DesiredParentTag UserName="admin" UserId="1" timestamp="2016-03-27T17:06:10.764+03:00">
        <DesiredChildTag operation="delete">
            <action startInstant="2016-03-30T08:35:00+03:00" id="244078"/>
            <action startInstant="2016-03-29T08:35:00+03:00" id="244078"/>
        </DesiredChildTag>
        <DesiredChildTag operation="insert">
            <action id="2" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
        </DesiredChildTag>
        <DesiredChildTag operation="update">
            <action id="222" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
            <action id="45" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
        </actions>
    </DesiredParentTag>
</root>
```

Desired XML OUTPUT:

```
    <DesiredParentTag UserName="admin" UserId="1" timestamp="2016-03-27T17:06:10.764+03:00">
        <DesiredChildTag operation="delete">
            <action startInstant="2016-03-30T08:35:00+03:00" id="244078"/>
            <!--excluded duplicate id if operation='delete'-->
        </DesiredChildTag>
        <DesiredChildTag operation="insert">
            <action id="2" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
        </DesiredChildTag>
        <DesiredChildTag operation="update">
            <action id="222" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
            <action id="45" startInstant="2016-03-21T08:35:00+03:00"/>
        </actions>
    </DesiredParentTag>
```

I want to copy all that's under the "DesiredParentTag" and if the operation="delete" to exclude the action tags that have the same id. Everythhing else just regular copy.

My current xsl: (it copies the tags I need and the attributes but doesn't exlucude the duplicates if the attirbute operation='delete')

```
<xsl:key name="ok" match="DesiredParentTag/DesiredChildTag/action" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="*">

    <xsl:copy-of select="DesiredParentTag[count(key('ok',@id)[1]|.)=1]"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stylesheet that does not copy the duplicates:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="id" match="DesiredChildTag[@operation = 'delete']/action" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @id)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//DesiredParentTag"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DesiredChildTag[@operation = 'delete']/action[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('id', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @id))[1]))]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh47.

Or in an XSLT 2.0 version:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="id" match="DesiredChildTag[@operation = 'delete']/action" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//DesiredParentTag"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DesiredChildTag[@operation = 'delete']/action[not(. is key('id', @id, ..)[1])]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh47/1.